# Using multiple REGEXP_LIKE statements within single DB2 query

Tags: sql, db2, regexp-like

I'm trying to understand the contents of an unstructured field. I can do this with multiple queries, but I'm struggling to write a query which pulls everything I need in one succinct dataset.

Here's a contrived sample:

```
UID  DATA
832  9a4b98f8ffb8e8c972
833  NULL
834  ABG:02-642960
835  www.web.com/page2
836  Amazon Kindle
837  vrx:49275004
838  p=a7039&v=ann@web.net&x=page4
839  https://pme.net/app4
```

The following query does work:

```
SELECT A.DATA AS PROD_CODES
FROM TABLE AS A
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(A.DATA, '[a-zA-Z]{3}:+[0-9]{2,8}[\-[0-9]{6,8}]?', 'i');
```

Here's the output:

```
PROD_CODES
ABG:02-642960
vrx:49275004
```

Here's what I'm trying to get:

```
    ROW_COUNT  PRODUCT_COUNT  URL_COUNT
            8              2          2
```

Here's the query I'm working with:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT,
    COUNT(CASE
      WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(A.DATA, '[a-zA-Z]{3}:+[0-9]{2,8}[\-[0-9]{6,8}]?') THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END) AS PRODUCT_COUNT,
    COUNT(CASE
      WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(A.DATA, '[a-zA-Z]{3,}\.(com|net)\/[a-z0-9]+') THEN 1
      ELSE 0 END) AS URL_COUNT
FROM TABLE AS A;
```

Which returns:

```
ROW_COUNT  PRODUCT_COUNT  URL_COUNT
        8            8            8
```

I'll add the comment that I need the ability to use `REGEXP_LIKE` because there are multiple data types that I intend to account for.

Comment: Just use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`, `COUNT` tells how many rows have a non null value and 0 is not null

Comment: Oh my, I can't believe I overlooked something that easy. I think that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

As nfgl mention in his comment, your query will count every row. Either replace count with sum or replace 0 with null

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT,
    COUNT(CASE
      WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(A.DATA, '[a-zA-Z]{3}:+[0-9]{2,8}[\-[0-9]{6,8}]?') THEN 1
    END) AS PRODUCT_COUNT,
    COUNT(CASE
      WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(A.DATA, '[a-zA-Z]{3,}\.(com|net)\/[a-z0-9]+') THEN 1
    END) AS URL_COUNT
FROM TABLE AS A;
```

NULL is the result from case if it does not match the CASE(s) so you dont need the ELSE(s)